# how using FTP service in Oracle form!

Tags: oracle, ftp, oracle9i, oracleforms, ftp-client

I am using Oracle forms for my application.
I would like to copy one directory from my local computer to a ftp address.
would you please help me how I can handle this problem in oracle forms or is it possible or not? is there any facility do it for me easily?
I thinking about using command prompt but I do not have any idea about how I can control every thing I mean it should not be reliable. because 100% I need to sure all files copy to the destination folder.

I need to handle all error like not enough space in ftp.

P.S. dont forget I am using oracle form. if you provide any code I am so appreciate you.

Thanks.

---

I googling a little bit I arrive to this code :
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/FTPFromPLSQL.php

I want to know how we can send one folder? It is so hard for me find all the object inside of my folder :(

Comment: have a look at UTL_FTP http://sourceforge.net/projects/plsqlftp/files/utl_ftp-1.0-alpha/utl_ftp-1.0-alpha

Answer (score 2):

If you look at what's going on in the referenced code, you'll see that they are calling shell commands from Oracle, as it has no built-in FTP functionality. What you'd need to do is similarly write a shell script to return the contents of the directory (using `ls` on *nix I assume).